# At what point should naturalism be doubted?

Tags: naturalism, doubt

Suppose you believe in naturalism. Now, there are things that happen in the world explainable by natural laws. One can also conceive of events happening that are not explainable by current natural laws.

The question is two fold.

1.) Should any events explainable by current natural laws make you doubt naturalism?

The answer to this may **seem** obviously no but one can imagine situations where this doesn’t seem so intuitive. Think of an event that we consider improbable and meaningful such as one being able to have dreams that are predictively accurate every single time. This is still technically explainable through natural laws (I.e. chance) but many, I wager, would believe in some other force being the cause if enough correct dreams occurred and were measured.

2.) Should any events not explainable through natural laws make you doubt naturalism? For example, if your dead grandmother revived tomorrow and said that God did it, should you doubt naturalism, or should you assume that there is some sort of natural law (as opposed to God for example) that is causing this?

Comment: To preempt: "Should any events explainable by current natural laws..." random chance is not an explanation of anything - it is just a statistical model that encodes regularities in the behaviour of a system but gives no insight into why it behaves that way.  If the natural laws only "explain" the observations with low probability, that is an indication that the natural laws are barely consistent with the observations, and thus do **not** explain them - the observations are a surprise assuming the natural law applies.

Comment: How is this a polemic question? Stop reading things into questions just because you want to.

Comment: Anyways, that can’t be true. You do realize that every event that occurred in the world is technically improbable right? Me tossing a coin 100,000 times results in a sequence that has a probability of 1/2^100,000. Thus, this sequence is incredibly improbable under chance. Yet this is no reason to rule out chance.

Comment: But we do not live computing probability of events.. What is the reason you think so?

Comment: "You do realize that every event that occurred in the world is technically improbable right?" nope, I flip a coin, it comes up heads, the probability was approximately 0.5.  would you say that was "technically improbable" - I wouldn't.

Comment: The event can be described in such a way in that it is improbable. The probability of you deciding to flip that coin at your particular location at the particular time you did is improbable. Anyways, this is irrelevant to the point I made. You would agree that any coin toss sequence of 100,000 coin tosses is extremely improbable. Does this mean chance didn’t cause it?

Comment: "Does this mean chance didn’t cause it?" there is no randomness in the macroscopic world, so random chance can't cause ***anything***.  Randomness is just a statistical model used to predict regularities in the behaviour of a system that you cannot model directly, ususaly because it is chaotic and sensitive to unknown initial conditions or it involves too many variables for the calculation to be feasible (e.g. statistical mechanics).  I have pointed that out to you repeatedly, including in an answer to a question you have already posed.

Comment: I've also explained to you about how compound events work and that adding additional specifiers will reduce the probability, and that if you want to know a probability of a head you need to marginalise (sum) over all of the event space that is consistent with the event you are talking about.  Substituting a different event is just evasion.

Comment: Well actually, proposed randomness in the microscopic world can travel up to the macroscopic. Either way, the term “by chance” doesn’t mean literally mean “by chance.” It’s a colloquial term to refer to a process that isn’t intentioned. But you already know this so why the need to make this irrelevant point? Again, does a coin landing on a particular sequence 100,000 times invalidate it occurring without intention? Yes or no? If no, then we have an example of an event that is improbable under a certain hypothesis without invalidating the hypothesis. This contradicts what you said earlier.

Comment: "It’s a colloquial term to refer to a process that isn’t intentioned. " what do you mean by "intentioned"?  "Again, does a coin landing on a particular sequence 100,000 times invalidate it occurring without intention?" again, what do you mean by "intention"?

Comment: As in, was it done by design?

Comment: That is no better, if I flip a coin I have expectations of what I will be likely to observe, but it doesn't happen via design or because I want it to happen that way.  Randomness is, as I said used to cover a lack of knowledge or an inability to consider all of the variables.  That is nothing to do with intention or design.  The probability of a hurricane hitting the south of England on a particular date can be estimated, but there is no design or intention about whether it should.

Comment: If we could perfectly use Bayesian statistics the question would be: "Based on all of the observations I've experienced, is it more likely that (1) there is a natural law I haven't discovered yet or (2) is it more likely that these observations occurred under the natural laws I already discovered." And the follow up question is "how much more likely?" -- Your answer will depend on how much time you've spent searching for undiscovered natural laws, how frequently you find new natural laws, how accurate you think your observations are, etc.

Comment: How do you tell the difference between "events not explainable through natural laws" and events not *yet* explained (but in principle explainable) through natural laws? This just sounds like it leads to some [god of the gaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_of_the_gaps) claim.

Answer (score 4):

Your first question is

> 1.) Should any events explainable by current natural laws make you doubt naturalism?

Such events would provide reasons to believe current natural laws (subject always to allowing for the possibility of a refutation). They could not possibly provide any reason to doubt it.

You seem to recognize this, but continue

> Think of an event that we consider improbable and meaningful such as one being able to have dreams that are predictively accurate every single time. This is still technically explainable through natural laws (I.e. chance)

"Chance" is not an explanation. It amounts to "cause unknown". That's all. (Quantum physics is a special and complicated case.) See the answer to your second question.

Your second question is

> 2.) Should any events not explainable through natural laws make you doubt naturalism?

An event not explainable by natural laws should make you doubt those laws and look for some as yet undiscovered laws that can explain it (and all the events explained by existing laws). For naturalism (as I understand it), inexplicable phenomena are classified as "anomalies" and the locus of a search for new natural laws (or elaborations of existing natural laws).

Naturalism in this context is not an empirical hypothesis to be refuted by events. It is a methodological principle which guides the search for natural laws. Different definitions of them are available. See [Wikipedia - Scientific Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_law) or [SEP - Natural Laws](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/laws-of-nature/)

But if you are inclined to believe your imagined resurrected grandmother's claim, I suggest you consider [Hume's argument against miracles - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Of_Miracles). Hume claims that a naturalistic explanation of an anomalous event will always be more plausible than a super-natural one.

It's worth adding that Hume does admit to believing in one miracle - the resurrection of Jesus, but on grounds of faith, not of reason. In other words, he accepts that to believe your grandmother would not be rational, though you may have other motivations to believe it.

Comment: "*"Chance" is not an explanation. It amounts to "cause unknown". That's all.*" The proponents of ontic randomness in quantum physics would disagree. But this answer is good altogether (+1).

Comment: Yes, I forgot to include the usual qualification for the quantum world. My mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[The Catholic Church & Canonization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonization) is a good starting point *ex mea (humble) sententia*. Gives us a rough idea or at least a grainy picture of *when* naturalism should be *doubted*.

The Catholic Church has a long list of *saints*, each one of them has (a) *miracle(s)* (inexplicable within naturalism, aka science) attributed to them. The process, as far as I can tell, is a bona fide court case, complete with an *advocatus Dei* (God's advocate) vs. an *advocatus diaboli* (Devil's advocate).

Comment: I've often wondered about the rules of evidence for those courts. But somehow, there's always been something more interesting to look into.

Answer (score 0):

> Should any events not explainable through natural laws make you doubt
> naturalism?

My HPS is bad, but no many things are or have been inexplicable, even needing an entirely new paradigm and language, and that's not sufficient to give up on explaining them naturally.

> Should any events explainable by current natural laws make you doubt
> naturalism?

Any event whatsoever? This has come up, and a *violation* of natural law as we presently understand them is usually thought of as necessary for a miracle claim.

Do you mean that **only** miracle claims can be used to argue against naturalism, and that these are of course impossible? Yes, science is a very successful enterprise empirically. Have you heard of the word *scientism*?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientism

Yours is quite full blooded. I might ask *why* you assume it? There is a lot of disagreement in philosophy, but that does not mean that it goes nowhere, that we don't learn more and more about what is right and wrong about our unscientific claims.

It may not generate substantive positive knowledge, but that's a question for philosophy and not scientism.

Comment: Could you please clarify the paragraph about miracle claims? The sentences individually make sense, but I can't see the connection between them. Thanks.

Comment: OK is that clear @LudwigV ? I can see why it might be a little confusing, and perhaps i try to be too didactic.

Comment: i was just going for no but who cares @LudwigV

Comment: It is much better. I can at least see what you're getting at. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start by being clear on our terms. *Naturalism,* according to *Brittanica* is:

> a theory that relates scientific method to philosophy by affirming that all beings and events in the universe (whatever their inherent character may be) are natural. Consequently, all knowledge of the universe falls within the pale of scientific investigation
> https://www.britannica.com/topic/naturalism-philosophy

To be clear, this *is* a belief system. Its core assumptions are unprovable, since we can't observe all beings and events in the universe, and since we don't have uncontroversial purely natural explanations even for all of the things we can observe.

With that said, it's not an actual religion. There's no book of Naturalism to outline the dogmas and heresies, and no Pope of Naturalism to make a definitive ruling. So there's really no objective answer to your question. If you are a naturalist, you'll have to make your own decisions on whether or not there's a breaking point to your faith. (I could tell you where I would personally jump off the wagon, but that's of limited value, since I'm not a naturalist in the first place.)